# Why can't I chain this series of lodash calls?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

This code:

```
  _(gameState.loot)
  .pick((value, key) -> key isnt "pickUpAnimations")
  .filter ((d) -> _.isArray (d))
  .reduce ((sum, d) -> sum.concat (d))
```

Is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '(function(d) {
```

Whereas this code works fine:

```
  removedAnimations = _.pick(gameState.loot, (value, key) -> key isnt "pickUpAnimations")
  removedAnimations = _.filter removedAnimations, ((d) -> _.isArray (d))
  removedAnimations = _.reduce removedAnimations, ((sum, d) -> sum.concat (d))
  removedAnimations
```

To me it seems that these should be doing the same thing.  The schema of `gameState.loot` looks like this:

```
loot: {
  ttl: 6000
  slowBlinkWhenTtlLessThanPercent: 60
  fastBlinkWhenTtlLessThanPercent: 30
  resurrections: []
  gold: []
  health: []
  equipment: []
  pickUpAnimations: []
}
```

BTW, this is the javascript being generated from the first example:

```
return _(gameState.loot).pick(function(value, key) {
  return key !== "pickUpAnimations";
}).filter((function(d) {
  return _.isArray(d);
}).reduce((function(sum, d) {
  return sum.concat(d);
})));
```

---

I tried @Blender's suggestion of this:

```
  _(gameState.loot)
    .pick (value, key) -> key isnt "pickUpAnimations"
    .filter (d) -> _.isArray (d)
    .reduce (sum, d) -> sum.concat (d)
```

But that gave me this error:

```
>> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '"pickUpAnimations".filter(function(d) {
```

Here's how the javascript looks like:

```
return _(gameState.loot).pick(function(value, key) {
  return key !== "pickUpAnimations".filter(function(d) {
    return _.isArray(d.reduce(function(sum, d) {
      return sum.concat(d);
    }));
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what's the issue but you can remove some of those parenthesis https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/8838052

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the generated JavaScript with better indentation:

```
_(gameState.loot).pick(function(value, key) {
    return key !== "pickUpAnimations";
}).filter(
    (function(d) {
        return _.isArray(d);
    }).reduce((function(sum, d) {
        return sum.concat(d);
    }))
);
```

As you can see, `.filter (...` and `.filter(...` are not the same. Two possible fixes:

1. Remove the whitespace between the method names and the opening parentheses:

   ```
   _(gameState.loot)
       .pick((value, key) -> key isnt "pickUpAnimations")
       .filter((d) -> _.isArray (d))
       .reduce((sum, d) -> sum.concat (d))
   ```
2. Remove the parentheses entirely:

   ```
   _(gameState.loot)
       .pick (value, key) -> key isnt "pickUpAnimations"
       .filter (d) -> _.isArray (d)
       .reduce (sum, d) -> sum.concat (d)
   ```

You can also get rid of the anonymous function calling `_.isArray`:

```
    _(gameState.loot)
        .pick (value, key) -> key isnt "pickUpAnimations"
        .filter _.isArray
        .reduce (sum, d) -> sum.concat (d)
```

Comment: I was looking at the generated code compared to what I put in the comment above and yes, this is indeed the issue.

Comment: This errors in a different way for me.  See thew edit in my question.

Comment: Thanks to your help and looking at the javascript, I realized that I wasn't using Coffeescript 1.7.1 like I thought I was.  I had to update my grunt-contrib-coffeescript plugin.

Comment: @tieTYT Note that none of the proposed fixes are necessary if you are running CoffeeScript 1.7.  Your original code compiles just fine.

Comment: @AaronDufour I thought it should.  That's what confused me so much.  I had the latest coffeescript, but apparently I had to upgrade grunt-contrib-coffee to be able to use the latest in my grunt project.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Are you sure? I tested it with 1.7.1 and the generated JavaScript didn't change.

Comment: [Yeah, pretty sure.](http://goo.gl/fkH98u)  The CoffeeScript website has an as-you-type compiler running the latest version.  Could you have mixed up global/local installs when you updated?

Comment: @AaronDufour: I see exactly the same code as the JavaScript from OP's question.

Comment: Look at lines 5 and 7.  In the question, they contain 1 and 3 close parens, respectively.  On the CoffeeScript website, they contain 2 close parens each.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Ohh, I see what you mean. Yes, that's definitely true.

Comment: IMO, If you have to look at the ultimately generated javascript, then it seems like something is wrong with coffeescript :(

Answer (score 2):

Darkside of coffeescript:

```
_(gameState.loot).pick(function(value, key) {
  return key !== "pickUpAnimations";
}).filter((function(d) {
  return _.isArray(d);
}).reduce((function(sum, d) {
  return sum.concat(d);
})));
```

Notice the extra `(` before your filter callback. What is happening is you're calling:

```
(function(d) { return _.isArray(d); }).reduce(...
```

Which will fail. Fix your curlies and you're good to go.